# How can I use a glob in Java to match files in directory and subdirectories?

Tags: java, glob

I have a situation where I need to match files along a specific path, and capture all files matching in that directory and any subdirectories. As a requirement, I must start from a base root directory, and that path is immutable. For example, assume that I have `some/root/dir/foo/bar.java` and `some/root/dir/foo/baz/quux.java`. If I attempt to run the following code, I do not get the results I desire:

```
private static void findMe(String srcPath, String matcherPattern) throws IOException {
  final List<Path> filePaths = new ArrayList<>();
  final PathMatcher matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher(matcherPattern);
  Files.walkFileTree(srcPath, new SimpleFileVisitor<>() {
    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
      if (matcher.matches(file)) {
        filePaths.add(file);
      }
      return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
  });
  filePaths.forEach(filePath -> System.out.println(filePath.toString()));
}
```

Given my requirements, I must use `"some/root"` as my value for the `srcPath` argument. However, if I use `findMe("some/root", "glob:**/foo/*.java")`, I get only my first file; if I use `findMe("some/root", "glob:**/foo/**/*.java")`, I get only my second file. Is what I'm trying to do just not possible with a glob? I'd be more than happy to replace the glob with a regex, if I can accomplish it that way, but I'm unsure how to structure that regex either.

Comment: If you want to match any `.java` file inside 'some/root/foo' and its subdirectories, use `findMe("some/root/foo", "**.java")`

Comment: @Aaron Yes, I could restrict the starting location that way, if I were able to accomplish that, but my requirements are otherwise. Assume, for the sake of this question, that the source location _must_ be `"some/root"`. I'll edit the question to reflect this requirement.

Comment: `**/foo/**.java` then ? Without the leading `**` if foo will always be directly inside the root dir

Comment: @Aaron There it is. That ought to get the job done. I hadn't considered using `**` as part of the file name segment of the matcher. If you want to add that as an answer, I'll gladly accept and upvote.

Comment: I'm not sure why your second glob didn't work in the first place though, so I'd rather wait for someone more knowledgeable to come up with an answer. Glad I could help anyway !

Comment: @Aaron That's my exact confusion too, and the whole reason I posted the question in the fir\st place. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first glob didn't match the second file because there was no `**` between `/foo` and `.java` to match the potential subdirectories.

Your second glob didn't match the first file because there were two slashes between `/foo` and `.java` that couldn't be matched for `.java` files at the root of `/foo/`

I suggest using `/foo/**.java` if the `foo` directory is always at the root of the directory you are searching in, or `**/foo/**.java` otherwise.